# 'modmap' replacment in new versions of MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB file that uses the 'modmap' function, but unfortunately this function doesn't exist in the latest versions of MATLAB.
So I need to Know what's the new function that replaces 'modmap'

Answer (score 0):

If the function is not available anymore you can still use it manually. The m-file of this function can be found [here](https://lost-contact.mit.edu/afs/cs.stanford.edu/package/matlab-r2009b/matlab/r2009b/toolbox/comm/commobsolete/modmap.m). Although, it is important to figure out why MATHWORK removed the function from the communication toolbox.